# Jquery string replace, only replacing the start of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have this code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var catURL = window.location.pathname;
    var catTitle = catURL.split("/");
    catTitleNew = catTitle[4].replace("-", " ");
    alert(catTitleNew);
    //this will alert will convert this-is-my-title to this is-my-title
</script>
```

And I dont think my replace code is working, its only replacing the first `"-"` how to I get it to replace all the `"-"` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
catTitleNew = catTitle[4].replace(/-/g, " ");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmpG6/)